# Form controls not rendering

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having troubles rendering my custom non blocking 'MessageBox' like form. So I have made my Alert form:

```cs
public partial class Alert : Form
{
    public Alert(string title, string text)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = title;
        labelText.Text = text;
    }

    private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

and looks like this in designer:

[image]

But when I try to open this Alert form within my main form like this:

```cs
var alert = new Alert("Test", "Hello, this is test.");
alert.Show();
```

Then my Alert form renders like this:

[image]

Where is my button and label?

//EDIT

`alert.ShowDialog();`

renders the form as intended

The method I'm using this form in:

```cs
    private void buttonTestConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f = new Alert("Test", "Hello, this is test");
        f.Show();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        var result = TestSqlConnection(); // This may that a while 
        if (result)
        {
            f.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            f.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Test", "Connection failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `alert.ShowDialog();` and see what happens

Comment: Hmm, that does work. But it blocks any following code. How can I make a non blocking MessageBox then?

Comment: "non blocking"  Do you perhaps have some kind of tight code loop you're trying to run in the background while this "non blocking" form is being displayed?

Comment: @Idle_Mind I've updated the question with full method usage.

Comment: The `Thread.Sleep(2000);` causes your main UI thread to stop responding, preventing the correct display of the form.

Comment: Never call `Thread.Sleep();`

Comment: Ouch, and what can I use to have a little delay between the Alert showing and starting the TestSqlConnection method?

Comment: You need to look in to async/await pattern.

Comment: @Andy Like asynchronously test the server connection? I agree on that but I would like to display the Alert form for some time even if the response comes right away.

Comment: I added an answer showing an idea of what you could do in the meantime.

Comment: I don't get it, what is non-blocking about the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI thread renders your UI. You are blocking the UI thread by calling `Thread.Sleep`. `Thread.Sleep` has it's place in programming, but not in UI programming.

My suggestion would be to move to asynchronous programming. For example:

```
private async void buttonTestConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = new Alert("Test", "Hello, this is test");
    f.Show();
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    var result = await Task.Run(() => TestSqlConnection());
    if (result)
    {
        f.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test successful",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        f.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Test", "Connection failed",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Notice the `async` keyword added to your method signature and calls to `await`.

I won't go in to how this works as there are many, many tutorials online. Here is a [great place](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) to start. The guy is a resident genius around here when it comes to this pattern.

Typically SQL connections can be converted to asynchronous, so that `Task.Run` should be temporary until you figure out the pattern.

Comment: Brilliant! I still have a lot to learn. Thank you :)

Comment: @popcorn -- you are very welcome. It's a super fun pattern to use. Confusing at first, but awesome once you get there.

Answer (score 1):

Another quick example:

```
private async void buttonTestConnection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonTestConnection.Enabled = false;

    using (var f = new Alert("Test", "Hello, this is test"))
    {
        f.Show();
        bool result = await Task.Run(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            return TestSqlConnection();
        });
        MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test " + (result ? "successful" : "failed"), 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            (result ? MessageBoxIcon.Information : MessageBoxIcon.Error));
    }

    buttonTestConnection.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want a `MessageBox` running outside the UI thread.

Comment: True...that will lead to the MessageBox not blocking the Alert Form.  Fixed it.

Comment: BTW, i didn't downvote your answer. I figured it was a simple oversight from you and you'd fix it eventually.

Comment: No biggie.  Up/Down votes don't really bother me.

Comment: Thank you for your post as well. I like that you disable the button as well. I overlooked that.